# Is there a way to get a Class Item (with custom Adapter) from long-clicked ListViewItem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I've :
a class

```
class Cars (Val Name String, Val Type String, Val Year String)
```

A mutable list

```
var listeCars : MutableList<Cars>? = null
```

a menu with Edit and Delete menu items
a listview with custom adapter
this listview is registred for context menu

```
registerForContextMenu(listView)

override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val info = item.menuInfo as AdapterContextMenuInfo
        val carx = listeConsultations!![info.position]
```

// The last line won't work, even if i use this instead

```
val carx = listView.adapter.getItem(info.position) as Car
```

// because i want to retrieve the Car class item to do some actions with it like this,

```
        return when {
            item.itemId == R.id.menuDelete -> {
                deleteCar(carx)
                true
            }
            item.itemId == R.id.menuEdit -> {
                updateCar(carx)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onContextItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

private fun updateCar(carx: Car?) {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(applicationContext)
    builder.setTitle("Edit Car")
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_car,null)
// .....
}

private fun updateCar(carx: Car?) {
// .....
}
```

Comment: Why don't those two lines work, exactly? Are you getting errors? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

   when(item){

      is Cars -> {

          //item is Cars Type in this brace
      }
   }

 ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't help, the compiler gives this error message
Incompatible types: Cars and MenuItem !
Thanks for trying !

Comment: @MohamedBenattou   Why do you pass the `MenuItem` instead of pass `Cars`?

Comment: From **Google** : 
`override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val info = item.menuInfo as AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.edit -> {
            editNote(info.id)
            true
        }
        R.id.delete -> {
            deleteNote(info.id)
            true
        }
        else -> super.onContextItemSelected(item)
    }
}` @huange 12345